# Wavelets: Relative error vs compression ratio

Tags: plotting, wavelet-analysis

I need to plot the relative error vs compression ratio diagram of a discrete wavelet transform on an image, but no luck so far ..
Here's the problem in short:

1. random_image.jpg
2. compress the image
3. plot the relative error vs compression ratio diagram

Here's the code and below is the link I am using as a reference:

```
cumulativeEnergy[data_] := 
 Module[{c = Sort[Flatten[data]^2, Greater]}, Accumulate[c]/Total[c]]

data = (* insert random image*)

wtdata = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data]

wtE = cumulativeEnergy[Last /@ wtdata[Automatic]];

ListLinePlot[Sqrt[1 - wtE]]
```

The problem is I don't get a curve like in the example..

[Tutorial used as a reference](http://www.math.kemsu.ru/kma/archiv/wav_math_htm/322_Ru.htm)

Thank you !

Comment: What do you get?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the old *Mathematica* wavelet explorer, the one used in the tutorial, coefficients were arranged in decreasing order of energy. You can see that from the following line from the tutorial,

```
In[8]:= Dimensions /@ wtdata
Out[8]= {{32,32},{3,32,32},{3,64,64}....}
```

In the new Mathematica 8 wavelets the coefficients are arranged in increasing order of energy as seen from the following example.

```
 In[1]:= data=ExampleData[{"TestImage","Boat"}];

 In[2]:= wtdata=DiscreteWaveletTransform[data]
Out[2]= DiscreteWaveletData[<<DWT>>,<9>,{512,512}]

 In[3]:= wpdata=DiscreteWaveletPacketTransform[data]
Out[3]= DiscreteWaveletData[<<DWPT>>,<4>,{512,512}]

 In[4]:= wtdata["Dimensions"]
Out[4]= {{0}->{1,256,256},{1}->{1,256,256},{2}->{1,256,256},{3}->{1,256,256},{0,0}->{1,128,128},{0,1}->{1,128,128},{0,2}->{1,128,128},{0,3}->{1,128,128},{0,0,0}->{1,64,64},{0,0,1}->{1,64,64},...
```

All you need to do is reverse the order of the coefficients,

```
In[5]:= wtE = Reverse@cumulativeEnergy[wtdata[Automatic, "Values"]];
In[6]:= wtP = Reverse@cumulativeEnergy[wpdata[Automatic, "Values"]];

In[81]:= ListLinePlot[{Sqrt[1 - wtE], Sqrt[1 - wtP]},AxesOrigin -> {1000, 0.1}, PlotLabel -> "relative error vs. compression ratio", PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanataion :) !

Comment: @Leonid It is nice to be part of the Mathematica community :-)